# When the WP_EDITOR button is pressed, the user is prompted to select a photo from their device

Tags: functions, uploads, editor, wp-editor

`wp_editor` has an Add Media button but when the user clicks that button, it opens the media library. I want to make a button that when clicked it allows uploading a image from *their device only*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Files are uploaded to the Media Gallery and then added to a post or a page from there. So even if you *can* force the "Add Media" button to only upload, the uploaded file will still end up in the site's Media Gallery.

Comment: i know that. I don't want the user to see the gallery of the whole site.

Comment: I suspect it's something that's possible, but it's going to take a lot of hands-on work.